# Exception Handling optimization in java

Tags: java, exception

I want to create a program that handles the 3 possible exceptions that occur when dividing two ints, asking the user to correct the input if it triggers an exception. The code only executes if no exceptions are triggered. The following code works, but I feel it is too unoptimized. Is there no other way, other than while loops, to continuously check for exceptions?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DivisionExceptions {

public int divide(int num, int den) {
    return num/den;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0,
        den = 0,
        a   = 0,
        b   = 0,
        c   = 0;

    DivisionExceptions div = new DivisionExceptions();

        while(a == 0) {
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce the first int"));
                a++;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error of type: " + e.getMessage() + ". Verify the information and try again.");
            }
        }
    while (c == 0) {    
        b = 0;
        while(b == 0) {
            try {
                den = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce the second int"));
                b++;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error of type: " + e.getMessage() + ". Verify the information and try again.");
            }
        }

        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Result of dividing: " + num + "/" + den + " is " + div.divide(num, den));
            c++;
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error of type: " + e.getMessage() + ". Verify the information and try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's fine the way it is, any optimization you make will be completely unnoticeable. You might want to clean up your tab spacing though.

Comment: When there is an ArithmeticException, they can only go back to try another value for `den`, but not `num`. Is that the intention?

Comment: @jingx yes, it is the intention, since there is no reason to modify the numerator if the denominator is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be simplified to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0, den = 0;

    DivisionExceptions div = new DivisionExceptions();

    while(true) {
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce the first int"));
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error of type: " + e.getMessage() + ". Verify the information and try again.");
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            den = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce the second int"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Result of dividing: " + num + "/" + den + " is " + div.divide(num, den));
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException | ArithmeticException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error of type: " + e.getMessage() + ". Verify the information and try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

~

Answer (score 0):

Well your code could use some refactor.

```
public class DivisionExceptions {

public int divide(int num, int den) {
    return num / den;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0,
            den = 0,
            a = 0,
            b = 0,
            c = 0;

    DivisionExceptions div = new DivisionExceptions();
    num = getNum(a, "Introduce the first int");
    den = getNum(b, "Introduce the second int");
    while (c == 0) {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Result of dividing: " + num + "/" + den + " is " + div.divide(num, den));
            c++;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error of type: " + e.getMessage() + ". Verify the information and try again.");
        }
    }
}

private static int getNum( int loopParam, String message) {
    int num = 0;
    while (loopParam == 0) {
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message));
            loopParam++;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error of type: " + e.getMessage() + ". Verify the information and try again.");
        }
    }
    return num;
}
}
```

I also allow myself to extract den calculation from **while(c==0)** loop, because it  always calculates same value but for n times, so you gain some optimilization here. If you can provide more information about why do you predefine all of your params as 0, than perhaps I could find some solution for that while(c==0) loop. If you use java 8 you could also extract your while loop to another method and give some Function as a param.